# Getting 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor' when updating spring-kafka to 2.4.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-kafka

We are using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.7.RELEASE. Now, we are planning to update the spring-kafka version to 2.4.0.RELEASE and getting below error on app startup

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor

Can you please suggest what am i missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah... For that feature you also need to upgrade a `spring-core` to `5.2.x` version. But with that it would be better to move your project fully to Spring Boot `2.2`. Otherwise it is going to be a lot of incompatibility. We never advertised that the latest Spring for Apache Kafka is going to work with that old Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for response. Would it be the same case with spring-kafka-2.3.0.RELEASE as well because I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Yes. That's true. That version is based on Spring Framework `5.2` as well and it is aimed for Spring Boot `2.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.